# Python: How to ignore # so that the line is not a comment?

Tags: python, comments, config

I'm having trouble using a config file, because the option starts with #, thus python treats it as a comment (like it should).

The part of the config file that is not working:

```
[channels]
#channel
```

As you may see, it's an IRC channel, that is why it needs the #. Now I could use some ugly method of adding the # everytime I need it, but I'd prefer to keep it clean.

So is there any way to ignore this? So that when I were to print the option, it would start with

Comment: Are you using a known configuration format, like INI?

Comment: Your config file is either valid Python code or it isn't. In the former case it needs to be formatted like any other Python code, and in the latter case you should *definitely* not just be feeding it into the Python interpreter. What's the context in which you're using this file?

Comment: Waleed, I am using an .ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using `ConfigParser` - which you should mention btw - then you have to pre-/postprocess the configfile before feeding it to the parser, because ConfigParser ignores the comment-parts.

I can think of two ways, both of them make use of the readfp, instead of the read-method of the ConfigParser-class:
1) subclass StreamWriter and StreamReader from the codecs-module and use them to wrap the opening-process in a transparent recoding.
2) use `StringIO` from the `io` module like:

```
from io import StringIO
...
s = configfile.read()
s.replace("#","_")
f = StringIO(unicode(s))
configparser.readfp(f)
```

And if you don't have to use an "ini"-file syntax take a look at the `json` module. I use it more often then the ini-file for configuration, especially if the config-files shouldn't be manually edited by simple users.

```
my_config={
  "channels":["#mychannel", "#yourchannel"],
  "user"="bob",
  "buddy-list":["alice","eve"],
  }

import json
with open(configfile, 'rw') as cfg:
  cfg.write(json.dumps(my_config))
```

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am pretty (very) new to all this. I just read the configparser docs, and I don't know what else to use to use my config file.

Comment: That would still give me the value without the #, correct? So I might as well just remove #'s from the config file, and add them during interpretation?

Comment: indeed. it would replace the '#' temporarily with another unlikely used, but valid char. i took the underline. but you could circumvent the whole issue by using the json-module. It would further have the advantage of allowing nesting and you could do a transparent conversion from dict to json and vice versa.

Comment: I am going to avoid this by setting the channels as values instead of options, so that the # isn't at the beginning of the line. That should fix it without having to implement a completely new module (as I said, I'm quite the beginner :p ). Thanks for your help, I will look into json when I decide to rewrite this whole thing again.

Comment: you need exactly two function from the json-module: `loads` and `dumps` - it's especially for beginners the most pain-free way imho.

Answer (score 2):

If your setting that in a python file you can escape the # with \

Otherwise I think that should be in a config file with other syntax that doesn't treat # as a commented line

Comment: I am using an INI file, and I am calling it with a SafeConfigParser() function. Does the file type matter when I am just calling it with that, because afaik it just loads it as raw text.

Answer (score 0):

ConfigParser has no way to not ignore lines beginning with '#'.

ConfigParser.py, line 476:

```
        # comment or blank line?
        if line.strip() == '' or line[0] in '#;':
            continue
```

No way to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

In your defense ConfigParser is letting you make this mistake:

```
import sys
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.add_section('channels')
config.set('channels', '#channel', 'true')

config.write(sys.stdout)
```

Produces this output:

```
[channels]
#channel = true
```

However you can give section names that start with a `#` like so:

```
import sys
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.add_section('#channels')
config.set('#channels', 'channel', 'true')

config.write(sys.stdout)

with open('q15123871.cfg', 'wb') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('q15123871.cfg')
print config.get('#channels', 'channel')
```

Which produces the output:

```
[#channels]
channel = true

true
```